# Manga where the main character is kicked out of Maou's army

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm searching for a manga that saw recently, but I can't find it.

This manga happens on a fantasy world. One day a kid is adopted/saved by the demon queen. He grows training with [Maou](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MaouTheDemonKing)'s generals, but is bullied for being weak. When he decides to flee, the generals don't care at first, but when Maou realizes he gets angry and commands them to recover him.

Once he is out, the main character realizes he is strong compared to common people.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it but clicking on the check mark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

[*Chillin' in My 30s After Getting Fired from the Demon King's Army*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chillin%27_in_My_30s_After_Getting_Fired_from_the_Demon_King%27s_Army)

[image: Front cover of the manga]

> Dariel is a soldier serving the demon army as aide to the demon lord Bashvaza, until he is fired by him. Having nowhere to go, Dariel sets out into the world when he saves the human girl Marika and is invited to her village. While things become worse in the demon army due to Dariel's absence, Dariel gets used to life among humans but is conflicted with his demon upbringing, as human and demon society have been at war for centuries.

Found with a search for `manga human kicked out of demon lord's army`